# How to fill a region between lines and a curve in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I browsed various questions but I cannot find what I need. I started using tikz yesterday, so I am very confused and my code is horrendous.
I am drawing a Penrose Diagram. This is where I am at:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (I) at (0,2) {};
\node (II) at (2,2) {};
\node (III) at (0,4) {};
\node (IV) at (-2,2) {};
\node (V) at (0,0) {};
\node (VI) at (2,0) {};
\node (VII) at (2,-2) {};

\draw[dashed] (III.center)--node[midway, above right]{$\mathcal{CH_{R}}$}(II.center)--node[midway, above right]{$\scri^{+}$}(VII.center)--(IV.center);       
\draw (IV.center)--node[midway, above left]{$\mathcal{CH_{L}}$} (III.center);
\draw (V.center)--node[near end, above left]{$\mathcal{H_{R}}$} (II.center);

\node (VIII) at (-0.5,1.2) {$\bullet$};
\draw (VI.center) to[out=170, in=-40, looseness=1.2] node[midway, below]{$\Sigma$} (VIII.center);

\path (VIII) +(45:2.3) coordinate (IX);

\fill[gray!20,nearly transparent] (VI) -- (-0.5,1.2) -- (IX) -- (II) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result is the following:

[image: Penrose Diagram 1]

My problem is that I want the grey region to extend to \Sigma, the curved line, but I do not know how to do it.

Also, for some reason, if I write

```
\fill[gray!20,nearly transparent] (VI) -- (VIII) -- (IX) -- (II) -- cycle;
```

in place of

```
\fill[gray!20,nearly transparent] (VI) -- (-0.5,1.2) -- (IX) -- (II) -- cycle;
```

I obtain something different, although (-0.5,1.2) are the coordinates of node (VIII). This is what happens:

[image: Penrose Diagram 2]

My main problem is filling the region, but any other tips are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry about it! Thank you for pointing it out. I will pay attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (I) at (0,2);
  \coordinate(II) at (2,2);
  \coordinate(III) at (0,4);
  \coordinate(IV) at (-2,2);
  \coordinate(V) at (0,0);
  \coordinate(VI) at (2,0);
  \coordinate(VII) at (2,-2);
  \coordinate (IX) at ($(II) +(135:1.2)$);
  \coordinate (VIII) at ($(IX) +(225:2)$);
  
  \fill[fill=gray!20] (VI.center) to[out=170, in=-40, looseness=1.2] node[text=black,midway, below]{$\Sigma$} (VIII.center) -- (IX.center) -- (II.center) -- cycle;
  \draw (VI.center) to[out=170, in=-40, looseness=1.2] (VIII.center);
  
  \draw[dashed] (III.center)--node[midway, above right]{$\mathcal{CH_{R}}$}(II.center)--node[midway, above right]{$\mathcal{I}^{+}$}(VII.center)--(IV.center);
  \draw (IV.center)--node[midway, above left]{$\mathcal{CH_{L}}$} (III.center);
  \draw (V.center)--node[near end, above left]{$\mathcal{H_{R}}$} (II.center);
  
  \node at (VIII) {$\bullet$};
  \fill (IX.center) circle [radius=2pt];
  
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\coordinate` instead of `\node`, since you just want to store the points.
Point IX wasn't on the edge: thus I first define this one and then VIII (but maybe it is no longer where you wanted).

Comment: Thank you! I will use your code to finally learn this skill. Yes, point IX was not on the edge because I was confused about how I could put it on the edge, so you have taught me how to do that too. Thank you very much!

Comment: To define IX somewhere between II and III, you can code `\coordinate (IX) at ($(II)!.3!(III)$);` where `.3` is the ratio of the distance.

Comment: The `intersections` library is also useful.